# Get multiple list from a single arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to get a multiple list of objects(Student) using an attribute(Location) of the particular object, the code is like below,

```
   List<Student> studlist = new ArrayList<Student>();
    studlist.add(new Student("1726", "John", "New York"));
    studlist.add(new Student("4321", "Max", "California"));
    studlist.add(new Student("2234", "Andrew", "Los Angeles"));
    studlist.add(new Student("5223", "Michael", "New York"));
    studlist.add(new Student("7765", "Sam", "California"));
    studlist.add(new Student("3442", "Mark", "New York"));
```

I need 3 separate lists here based on locations.

1.Newyork list
2.California list
3.Los Angeles list

Can anyone tell me the right way here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At a very simple level, you create the three lists you need, foreach over the main one, add each to their appropriate list by looking at the location. Are you looking for some special way?

Comment: User `Map`, key - Place and value - Student object list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Google Guava Collections:

```
ListMultimap<String, Student> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Student student : studlist)
    map.put(student.getLocation(), student);
```

Then you can get the New York `List` by doing

```
List<Student> newYorkers = map.get("New York");
```

If you aren't using Java 8 or Google Guava Collections, I don't think you can do much better than this:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();
for (Student student : studlist) {
    String location = student.getLocation();
    List<Student> list = map.get(location);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        map.put(location, list);
    }
    list.add(student);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple Java 8 construct like this would do the trick:

```
final Map<String, List<Student>> byLocation = 
    studlist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getLocation));
```

This creates a `Map<String, List<Student>>` that contains the three lists and uses the `location` as key (provided that the Student class has a `getLocation`-method).

To retrieve the "New York"-list simply use `byLocation.get("New York")`. To get all lists simply use `byLocation.values()` and you get an `Collection<List<Student>>` containing the lists.

Comment: Cool.. Is this works with only java8? Can I get this way in java7?

Comment: This is Java 8 only - the `Stream` API:s are part of Java 8 (which includes `Collectors` etc.

Comment: @Mary.Hansen I don't think there's any simple way in java7. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Mary.Hansen - There is no real elegant solution for this in Java 7 unless you add an external library like Guava (see pbabcdefp's answer). This is probably the easiest way to go: http://hastebin.com/egikekirof.coffee

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8:

```
List<Student> nyList = studlist.stream()
    .filter(s -> "New York".equals(s.getLocation()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Student> caList = studlist.stream()
    .filter(s -> "California".equals(s.getLocation()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Student> laList = studlist.stream()
    .filter(s -> "Los Angeles".equals(s.getLocation()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `HashMap` wrapper with the city as a key, so you group your students according to their cities eg

```
Map<String, List<Student>> studMap = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();
```

Comment: OP has a list though; it's not like the HashMap api is compatible with that of a List.

Comment: of course if there is such a requirement, OP may use this HashMap in parallel with the maintained List for fast search (but apparently with more reserved memory)

Comment: Ok, but the key here is how does OP get the lists. I think it'd be appropriate to demonstrate how this is done with the new data structure you're suggesting; even better - why? Then, of course, the question arises, why not use the map to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your class *Student* stores location in ***loc***.

```
  ArrayList<Student> newyorkList = new  ArrayList<Student>();

 ArrayList<Student> californiaList = new  ArrayList<Student>();

 ArrayList<Student> losangelesList = new  ArrayList<Student>();

for(int i = 0; i< studlist.size();i++){
      Student temp = (Student) studlist.get(i);

       If( (temp.loc).equals("New York") )
                  newyorkList.add(temp);

       If( (temp.loc).equals("California") )
                  californiaList.add(temp);

       If( (temp.loc).equals("Los Angeles") )
                  losangelesList.add(temp);

  }
```